# 'while' statement showing strange behaviour in php

Tags: php, while-loop

in the following code if I uncomment the print statement the code works fine.. prints '11' but after commenting it shows error of memory dump.
 How is it possible...  php version 5.5.9

```
public static function checkFinalLayerConditions($profileObj,$layerToShow,$interestsPending,$getTotalLayers) {
    $profileid = $profileObj->getPROFILEID();
    $picObj= new PictureService($profileObj);
    $havePhoto= $picObj->isProfilePhotoPresent();print($layerToShow);
    while (1) { //print($layerToshow);
      if ($layerToShow) {
        $show = 0;print($layerToShow); die();
        switch ($layerToShow) {
          case '1': if ($havePhoto == null)
                      $show=1;
                    break;
          case '2': if ($profileObj->getDetail("","","FAMILYINFO")[FAMILYINFO]=='')
                      $show=1;
                    break;          
          case '3': if ($interestsPending > 0)
                      $show=1;
                    break;            
          default : break;
        }
```

Comment: exactly how do you terminate this infinite loop? the `break` statements you have are going to break the `switch`, not the `while`.

Comment: Yup he is right.  Your while loop never ends.

Comment: please assume that it breaks anyhow.... however does that even matter as i have die() in the path.... so it must die there....  but it 'dies' only wen i introduce a print() just after opening the while as above.... in print()'s absence its memory dump...
also the value of $layerToShow is 1 always

Comment: you need to add two } for both If statement and the while, and you must add a solution to close the infinite while